# problem with create new project with zend server

Tags: zend-framework

i'm newbie in zend framework , i use zf command line tool to create new project like this : zf.bat create project zf_cms

after i run this command for first time everything ok and no-error occur but i expect project files exists on c:\program files\zend\apache2\htdocs but there is noting .

after that when i rerun command it says this project already exists !!

how can i create new project using zend command line tool or any other ways . tanks.

Answer (score 1):

At your command line, type: `cd c:\program files\zend\apache2\htdocs`
hit "enter"
and then, type in your `zf.bat` command

Answer (score 0):

It might be created under your default workspace... you can use symbolic link if you're using linux or mac to link your workspace with your apache... you also can use Zend Studio to create a new ZF project...